# Android Device specific Camera Path

Tags: android, camera

The project I am currently working on requires me to store Images/ Videos into the same folder as where the device native Camera stores them. As per my research I have found that each device stores the Images/Videos into a different name. That is Nexus-One stores its Camera files in to folder named "Camera" (/sdcard/DCIM/Camera). HTC Incredible stores its camera files into a folder named "100MEDIA" (/sdcard/DCIM/100MEDIA). Sony Xperia x10 stores its camera files into folder named "100ANDRO" (/sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO). I want to know if its programatically possible to get this path so that i can store the images/videos taken from my app to the same location.??? Is there any API that may help do it or any work around that is required. If so can u pls suggest me the same.

Please guys this is pretty urgent and important. Would really appreciate and be glad to get a response soon. Really looking forward to the replies. Thanks a ton in advancce...

Comment: See also answers for issues:

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566810/android-device-specific-camera-path-in-android
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248887/android-device-specific-camera-path-issue

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, only the [base directory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DCIM) for videos and photos is accessible in a standard way through the [Environment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) class. I think you'll have to let the user configure the target directory themselves. Nothing prevents you from making intelligent suggestions to the user, though.