# Check what mobile the user is using

Tags: java, android, android-camera, environment

Is their a way to check what mobile the user uses.
I will explain why I want to know this.

In my app, I must take photo's from the Camera path of the user.
In the samsung devices, that is DCIM/Camera.
But in the HTC devices, that is DCIM/100MEDIA.

So when I see the user got a HTC phone, I can change the Camera path string in my app.

Or is their a way to acces the Camera folder on phone?

I know how to acces the root:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

I already tried `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES;`
and `Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM;`

Maybe I use it in a wrong way.

Any Ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code to get manufacturer

```
String comp = Build.MANUFACTURER;
String model = Build.MODEL;
```

Answer (score 0):

using this code you can able to get the device name `String str = android.os.Build.MODEL;`

Answer (score 0):

To get to device name :

```
android.os.Build.MODEL;
```

[Found Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071281/get-android-device-name)

But in your case it will be better if you look directly for the default path using :

```
getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

If API level is below 7 and then append /Pictures to get the path of Photos storage.

```
getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
```

If API level > 7

[Found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248887/android-device-specific-camera-path-issue)

for more details visit this [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).Section : Saving files that should be shared

Comment: Hey, I tried this `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`
But that isn't reacting the same as `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); +"DCIM/Camera"`

Comment: The API is above 7 (10) So I used `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`
But that didn't work, however this works (on Samsung only then):
`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); +"/DCIM/Camera"` But as I said, I want to let it work on the HTC too (DCIM/100MEDIA).

I now check on Manufactor, then change the string, but I prefer your answer (if I can get it to work)