# Android NDK Camera Path getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, gallery

I am creating an App. I do not have any UI, if there is any, I am using OpenGL for that. So in short, I do not have any `Java` code. I am using `NativeActivity` sample for reference.

My need is to get Camera Path, which is device dependent. In Apps, where there is `Java Activity` available, it simple as stated in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248887/android-device-specific-camera-path-issue).

Is there any way to get get same functionality in completely native code? Is there an alternative?

I do not really want to add a java activity, since I have already created something with OpenGL. Adding Java Acivity only to get this string makes me feel fool over the period of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JNI from your native code to call the Java methods you want.

Try this from your native activity:

```
JNIEnv *env; 
state->activity->vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL); 

jclass envClass = env->FindClass("android/os/Environment");
jmethodID getExtStorageDirectoryMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(envClass, "getExternalStorageDirectory",  "()Ljava/io/File;");
jobject extStorageFile = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(envClass, getExtStorageDirectoryMethod);

jclass fileClass = env->FindClass("java/io/File");
jmethodID getPathMethod = env->GetMethodID(fileClass, "getPath", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
jstring extStoragePath = env->CallObjectMethod(extStorageFile, getPathMethod);
const char* extStoragePathString = env->GetStringUTFChars(extStoragePath);

//use extStoragePathString

env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(extStoragePath, extStoragePathString);
state->activity->vm->DetachCurrentThread();
```

If you want to use more Java methods, you may want to look into subclassing NativeActivity from Java and using a Java Helper class, like it's done inside the *Teapot* sample from the NDK.