How to access file from Camera resource of android
I desire to access media files from C code in android application.
I use this method to get file path  by file uri:
fun getFileNameThatICanUseInNativeCode(uri: Uri?, applicationContext: Context): String? {
    val  mParcelFileDescriptor =
        applicationContext.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri!!, "r")
    if (mParcelFileDescriptor != null) {
        val fd: Int = mParcelFileDescriptor.fd
        val file = File("/proc/self/fd/$fd")
        var path: String? = null
        try {
            path = Os.readlink(file.absolutePath).toString()
            mParcelFileDescriptor.close()
        } catch (e: ErrnoException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return path
    } else {
        return null
    }
}


This method return generally this path, which could be accessed from C code
/mnt/user/0/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/{fileName}
but for some phones it seems that the user folder is not found (maybe persmission issue, because the user folder is not acceable from adb shell (for example).
From adb shell, my file is also located here : /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/$fileName, this native_file_path also does not work
How to access this file from C code?
For some phones i can access for others no:
  if((file = fopen(native_file_path,"a"))!=NULL)


As the name might suggest, emulated/0 is not a native path, but it's emulated ...calling to Java through JNI might be an alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29695982/549372 ...while the difference is single vs. multi-user filesystem layout.

Your method returns storage/emulated/0. My method returns /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/ where the video is located. But fopen does not see it. Could you prompt why? I am checking on real device.

Android 13 and higher:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />

The code I used:
class ImageInDcim(private val context: Context) {

    fun listImagesInDCIM() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES), 100)
                return
            }
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 100)
                return
            }
        }
        
        val uri: Uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
        )
        
        val selection = "${MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA} LIKE ?"
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf("%/DCIM/%")

        val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
            uri,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            "${MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED} DESC"
        )

        cursor?.use {
            val columnIndexDisplayName = it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
            val columnIndexData = it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
            
            while (it.moveToNext()) {
                val displayName = it.getString(columnIndexDisplayName)
                val dataPath = it.getString(columnIndexData)

                println("Image found: $displayName at $dataPath")
            }
        }
    }
}


Yes, i request and grant READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and also get the path /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/myfile path but c fopen  method does not detect the file.

Don't set the directory storage/emulated/0 manually. Don't use/ use File.seperator instead

i use getFileNameThatICanUseInNativeCode function to get file path by uri.
For working phones it returns /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/myfile.mp4 and it  works.
For other phones it returns /mnt/user/0/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/myfile.mp4  and in this case i can't access it from the C code.  How to overcame this difference in file system of different phones?
