# Android device specific camera path in android

Tags: android

I created a sample app, in my app i capture a photo and save it in a specific folder. The app runs successfully on the emulator with target 2.3.3, but when installing it on a mobile the image gets stored in the default folder in `/mnt/sdcard.DCIN/100ANDRO/sample.jpg`. Please tell me how can I overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are OK with relying on x>= API level 8 you could use Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);